# Is there any way to combine all JS in a single file on Play Framework?

Tags: javascript, playframework, coffeescript, playframework-2.3

I use CoffeeScript in my Play project.

I would like to know if there is any way to combine all the CoffeeScripts into a single file.

Comment: Presumably you want to concatenate the rendered Javascript? One option (for any type of asset) is [sbt-concat](https://github.com/ground5hark/sbt-concat). For more fancy things you can use [sbt-rjs](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-rjs).

Comment: I looked sbt-concat, but i couldn't found a way to concat my js (from coffee) and js files from webjars. Do you know something about it? About the sbt-rjs I read somethings about it but I think I didn't found a document or article that explain to do what i want to do.